Azure Databricks Cluster creation issue
When I try to create an Azure Databricks cluster face the error simultaneously.
Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this issue?
subscription: $200, free subscription
The image below includes an error I received:

The image below includes other configurations:


Clusters requires public ip address more then your current quota. please increase the quota and try.

Hi @JayashankarGS, Can you guide how to increase the quota?

@RameshMadhubhashitha, please check the below answer.

The above error message says that the cluster creation uses 8 PublicIpAddress resource types, but it exceeds the allocated quota which is 3.
You need to increase the quota of the PublicIpAddress. To do that, in the portal, go to your subscription -> Under settings select Usage + quotas. In the Filters, select Networking and your region. Now, find the Public IP Address and create a new support request as shown below.

Next, you need to enter the required limit for it and submit the request.

You can refer this documentation to know more about it.
Additionally, to check which resources are accessing the Public Ip address, you can use below script in the Azure Resource graph explorer. You can get the names of the resources so that you can delete the unwanted extra resources which are using your Public Ip addresses.
resources
| where type contains 'publicIPAddresses' and isnotempty(properties.ipAddress)
| limit 100

Search for Azure Resource graph explorer in the portal and run the above script. Currently, I don't have any resources as per this case.

